# Anyone recognize this form for date storage?

Tags: r, time

I have values that came from a JSON blob and likely Excel before that.

There is a field for `timestamp` that includes values like these

```
timestamp = [
1519383511397, 1536864135321,
1540584502333, 1535641486675,
1541126656968, 1544634450352,
1538790352678, 1538171618112,
1546300725869, 1542642909566
]
```

I tried to convert them with `as.POSIXct(as.numeric(1519383511397), origin = "1970-01-01")`. That didn't work. I tried a few other variations, like setting the start year to `0-01-01` and `2000-01-01`.

Do you recognize this format and is there a better way to parse them?

Comment: What range do you expect the values to be in?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a Unix EPOCH13 timestamp, which counts in milliseconds, divding by 1000 yielded the following assuming unix time:

```
timestamp  <-  c(
  1519383511397, 1536864135321,
  1540584502333, 1535641486675,
  1541126656968, 1544634450352,
  1538790352678, 1538171618112,
  1546300725869, 1542642909566
  )

as.POSIXct(timestamp/1000,origin="1970-01-01")

[1] "2018-02-23 11:58:31 CET"  "2018-09-13 20:42:15 CEST" "2018-10-26 22:08:22 CEST" "2018-08-30 17:04:46 CEST" "2018-11-02 03:44:16 CET" 
 [6] "2018-12-12 18:07:30 CET"  "2018-10-06 03:45:52 CEST" "2018-09-28 23:53:38 CEST" "2019-01-01 00:58:45 CET"  "2018-11-19 16:55:09 CET"
```

Comment: I think the output is different from the expected output in OP's post.  I was initially thinking about 1000 division

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that it is javascript time which is parsed in milliseconds which can easily be converted.

```
timestamp = c(
  1519383511397, 1536864135321,
  1540584502333, 1535641486675,
  1541126656968, 1544634450352,
  1538790352678, 1538171618112,
  1546300725869, 1542642909566
  )

conv_ms <- as.Date(timestamp / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000), origin = as.Date("1970-01-01"))

R> conv_ms
 [1] "2018-02-23" "2018-09-13" "2018-10-26" "2018-08-30" "2018-11-02" "2018-12-12" "2018-10-06" "2018-09-28"
 [9] "2018-12-31" "2018-11-19"
```